# why does my recv call block?

Tags: c, tcp

I have a simple web service, that is accessible via HTTP. I have a c program that uses this service. For reasons I can't understand, my `recv` call is blocking for nearly 5 seconds. The size of the response is less than 600 bytes, and the API call takes less than 100ms (when called from a browser).

What could be causing this behaviour? I have tried using the TCP_NODELAY option, this seems to make no difference. The send command (which is similarly sized, and occurs immediately before the recv) is relatively fast.

EDIT: Code, as requested - the entire function is large, but this is the code in question:

```
connect(tcpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

char* args = cJSON_PrintUnformatted(root);
sprintf(request_string, "GET %s?json=%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n\r\n", API_PAGE, curl_easy_escape(NULL, args, strlen(args)), API_HOST);
send(tcpSocket, request_string, strlen(request_string), 0);
recv(tcpSocket, request_string, 4095,0);
```

EDIT2: tcpdump output

```
20:03:03.976311 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [S], seq 3254094788, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 83001890 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:03:03.976324 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [S.], seq 3772034334, ack 3254094789, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:03:03.976335 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890], length 0
20:03:03.976367 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:380, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890], length 379
20:03:03.976382 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [.], ack 380, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890], length 0
20:03:09.055255 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [P.], seq 1:605, ack 380, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83001890], length 604
20:03:09.055293 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [.], ack 605, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055310 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [F.], seq 380, ack 605, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055314 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [F.], seq 605, ack 380, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055320 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [.], ack 606, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055320 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [.], ack 381, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
```

Comment: waaay more details needed. first recv on the client or on the server? Show us the recv code

Comment: Have you tried using tcpdump/Wireshark to see when the request and response are sent over the wire?

Comment: @pm100, code added. The send and recv are both on the client, send to server, then await response.

Comment: @Barmar the API call is local (locally hosted service) for testing.

Comment: You can use `-i lo0` to capture traffic on the loopback interface.

Comment: @Barmar, I added the tcp dump for the time the program was running, there does appear to be a 5 second delay, any thoughts on what causes this?

Comment: It woiuld also be helpful to use `strace` on the server, to see when its `recv()` call returns and when it calls `send()`, and correlate these with the tcpdump timestamps.

Comment: That's one too many `\r\n` at the end, which could be confusing the server.

Comment: You are absolutely positive that it's your very first call to `recv` that blocks?

Comment: I think its todo with flushing the output of the server, I don't know why the browser displays it immediately, but if I call `flush()` in my server code, my client side `recv()` returns immediately, but now the http request contains a spurious "d8" between the headers of the response and the body. d8 is the hex for the length of the body. But as far as I can tell this is not part of the specification

Comment: forcibly adding the `content-length` header, removes the spurious "d8". So, my problem is now solved, I'm still interested in why this presents with `recv` but not with a browser call, is there a TCP option, or recv flag I can use to avoid this?

Comment: If you're implementing HTTP 1.1 you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616, especially the parts about content-length. And you can't write proper code without error checking every system call. You don't even know that the connect or the send succeeded, for example.

Comment: @EJP, the code above is simplified, I do check the return values of send, recv and connect. I also check for the content length field, to allow me to continue reading. That is all I require as the API I'm using is fairly basic. I thought I had understood the HTTP 1.1 spec, however the content length being prepended to the body I was not expecting

Comment: I see, there was a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header present, which follows a different specification, and includes the chunk size and optionally encoding prior to the message. Mystery solved :)

Comment: There's no `flush()` function in the standard C or Unix libraries. Do you mean `fflush()`? If you're using `stdio` in the server, you're running into its default buffering mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this problem was not due to anything occurring on the client, but an issue with the PHP server stalling the response. The solution was to flush the response immediately, before terminating the connection at the server.

It is not clear why this problem only presented itself when accessing the API from a programatic client, rather than a browser. It is possible that the browser used headers that ensured data was transmitted immediately, or passed arguments to the socket connection on the client to ensure that it processed returned data immediately, even if the connection was not deemed complete.

Answer (score 0):

Let us review the tcpdump:

First, TCP connection establishment:

```
20:03:03.976311 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [S], seq 3254094788, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 83001890 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:03:03.976324 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [S.], seq 3772034334, ack 3254094789, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:03:03.976335 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890], length 0
```

Next, data sent from client to server and ACK received:

```
20:03:03.976367 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:380, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890], length 379
20:03:03.976382 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [.], ack 380, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83001890 ecr 83001890], length 0
```

And, 5 seconds after !, the answer from server:

```
20:03:09.055255 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [P.], seq 1:605, ack 380, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83001890], length 604
20:03:09.055293 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [.], ack 605, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
```

finally, close connection:

```
20:03:09.055310 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [F.], seq 380, ack 605, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055314 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [F.], seq 605, ack 380, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055320 IP localhost.48732 > localhost.http: Flags [.], ack 606, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
20:03:09.055320 IP localhost.http > localhost.48732: Flags [.], ack 381, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 83003159 ecr 83003159], length 0
```

in conclusión, the server is causing the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is exactly what we discuss above in the comments. You've not really added anything here.

Comment: @ZackNewsham: transferred to community wiki. Please, try to do not leave questions without answers nor "accept" flag, even when solved in the comments.

Comment: @ZackNewsham Answers on SO are not only for you. The main reason they exist is to help future readers. That's why it's important to compile the solution into clear, readable answer post and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BartoszKP, fair enough - though I would argue that this answer doesnt qualify as a solution, as the problem didnt end up having anything to do with the client side function, but rather something to do with flushing from the server. I'll make an answer that explains the situation.